# nodejs - learning callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

```
function fun1(a) {
  console.log(a);
  formId(a, function (err, val) {
    console.log(val);//4
    return val;
  });
}

function formId(a, callback) {
  callback(null, a + 2);
}

console.log('er', fun1(2));//undefined
```

why I am getting undefined? The same result is with the arrow funtion.

Comment: The `fun1()` returns nothing, So when a function returns nothing and your console it that shows undefined.

Comment: ` z = formId(a, function (err, val) {
        console.log(val);
        return val;
    });
    return z; `
Tried this way

Comment: @jolly `formId` doesn't `return` anything either. And it really shouldn't, since it *only* provides its result to the callback. Especially if the callback was asynchronous, that would be flat out impossible.

Comment: Change the fun1 to also accept callback `function fun1(a, cb)...` then instead of `return val` use `cb(val)` and then change the `console.log('er', fun1(2));` to `fun1(2, function(val){ console.log(val);}`